# Need to add Logical Volume, but don't have lvm, and yum says I have no space

Tags: centos, yum, lvm, centos-7

I have a CentOS 7 server on SoftLayer. I only gave it 25GB of storage initially. Now it's full, so I ordered an additional 300GB of storage for it.

My understanding (which comes from [this article](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Adding_a_New_Disk_to_a_CentOS_6_Volume_Group_and_Logical_Volume)), is that in order to continue adding files to my existing file system, I need to add this new 300 GB drive to the existing logical volume.

To add it to my existing logical volume, I need to use a whole variety of commands... `pvcreate`, `pvdisplay`, `lvdisplay`... but none of those seem to be installed on this server.

So I need to install them. I found something suggesting that `yum install lvm2` would install those commands for me. This spits out a lot of output, ending with:

```
Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base
    * free   0
    * needed 100 k
```

Right back to my original problem - the server is full. I found a 42 M file under `/` that I didn't need anymore, so I deleted it. But `yum install lvm2` still gives me the exact same problem. This makes no sense to me - I removed 42000 k worth of file just now. That should have easily given `yum` the 100 k that it says it needs.

Checking my available space with `df -h` I see this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2       25G   24G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        911M     0  911M   0% /dev
tmpfs           918M     0  918M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           918M   89M  830M  10% /run
tmpfs           918M     0  918M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      240M  100M  124M  45% /boot
```

Okay... could be a rounding issue where it's showing something like 24.5 G as 25 G and 24.499 G as 24 G. So I double check without the h and see:

```
/dev/xvda2      25412940 24874028         0 100% /
```

What gives? I `rm`d a 42000 K file - why is it saying nothing is available?

So I have a few questions:

1. Why is `lvm2` not pre-installed on CentOS 7? Was it replaced with something newer that I should be using instead?
2. Why is there still no space available, after I `rm`d a 42000 K file under `/`? Is there something more I need to do to really make that space available, beyond just `rm`ing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from `df -h` output you dont have LVM partitions.
You might be over thinking the task.

Whats the output of `fdisk -l`?

If your host simply added 300GB to /dev/xvda2 all you need to do is grow the partition with `fdisk` and the filesystem using `resize2fs`
(sorry cant leave comments yet)

Comment: `fdisk -l` shows that I have two disks: /dev/xvda2, with 25 GB of storage, and /dev/xvdc, with 300 GB of storage. I know that I could just partition, format, and mount the drive, but that has the issue that I can't keep using my existing directories - I'd have to create an entirely new set of directories. My understanding is that lvm will allow me to avoid having to do that - I can just add both disks to a single logical unit and where the files are physically stored becomes an implementation detail only known by CentOS, not a detail I need to worry about.

Comment: In that case your approach will work, I just assumed you had a VM and that your host simply grew `/dev/xvda`
Keep in mind linux reserves 5% of / for root operations, you'll need to get at least 6% free space on /. If I was in your shoes I would not bother with LVM, I'd simply partition & mount '/dev/xvdc` where I need it most (ex: if i'm heavily using /home/. I'd create a partition on `/dev/xvdc`, copy contents of `/home/` over to new partition and mount it under /home/)...but that just me, good luck :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm realizing how difficult going with LVM is going to be so I think I'm just going to mount this disk like you just suggested. Thanks!